# How to insert data in multiple tables at a time?

Tags: asp.net, database, ms-access, database-design, relational-database

I have following tables in my MS Access database.
Personal, Partner, ContactDetails, NativeAddress bla bla bal. I created a **Wizard** in Visual Studio 2012 for above tables. A screenshot is given below. Now I want to submit all data at once in all tables when user presses the submit button. So what syntax should I use now. Please guide.

My code is something like this. Its incomplete and just beginning of my script. So please don't get me wrong.

```
 protected void dataWizard_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\micronets\jobwork-2013\arunthathiyar-sangham\arunthathiyar-web-application\App_Data\arunthathiyar-db.accdb";

    string personalDetails = "INSERT INTO PersonalDetails(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Sex, Age, DateOfBirth, PlaceOfBirth, EducationalQualification, EmploymentStatus, Profession, PhysicalStatus, BloodGroup) VALUES (@fnPD, @mmPD, @lnPD, @sexPD, @agePD, @dobPD, @pobPD, @eqPD, @esPD, @profPD, @phyicPD, @bgPD)";
    string familyDetails = "INSERT INTO FamilyDetails(Relationship, FullName, Status, BloodGroup, EducationalQualification, Profession, EmploymentStatus) VALUES(@relFD, @fnFD, @statusFD, @bgFD, @eqFD, @profFD, @esFD)";
    string contactDetails = "INSERT INTO ContactDetails(FlatBuildingStreet, Landmark, Area, City, Pincode, State, Country, Mobile, Telephone, Email) VALUES(@fbsCD, @landCD, @areaCD, @cityCD, @pinCD, @stateCD, @countryCD, @mobCD, @telCD, @emailCD)";

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        txtMemAmountReceived.Text = txtPDFirstName.Text;
    }
    catch
    {
        txtMemAmountReceived.Text = "Sorry";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're heading in the right direction.  Here's what you need to do next:

**Create an [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object**
You have a connection, now you need to create and Command object that can store the SQL text and execute commands against the database.  Something like this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(personalDetails, con);
```

**Open, execute, close**
Then, inside your try block, you want to open the connection, execute the query, and close the connection:

```
cmd.Connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Connection.Close();
```

**Rinse and repeat**
You can take it from there as far as executing all three queries.  You just need to update the `cmd.CommandText` property with the text for the other queries you want to execute, and call `ExecuteNonQuery` again.

Answer (score 0):

you could possibly concatenate all of your query strings into one separated by semicolons(;)  So the one large string would be sent to the server and each query would be processed and you would then only have to make one connection to the database.

```
string myQuery = personalDetails+ "; " + familyDetails + "; " + contactDetails
```

However i would just make 3 separate connections just so it will be easier to manage all of your parameters.  If you ever have to go back and change the query or a parameter it will be a mess.